# UIBarButtonItems Spacing Issue in iOS 11

Tags: swift4, ios11, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to adjust spacing between UIBar Button items.

[image: Navigation Bar]

```
func addLeftBarButtonItems() {

    let btn1 = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
    let list_icon = UIImage(named: "list") as UIImage?
    btn1.setImage(list_icon, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem()
    item1.customView = btn1

    let btn2 = UIButton()
    btn2.setTitle("Notification", for: .normal)
    btn2.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem()
    item2.customView = btn2

    let btn3 = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
    let redbadge = UIImage(named: "red_badge") as UIImage?
    btn3.setBackgroundImage(redbadge, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    btn3.setTitle("10", for: .normal)
    btn3.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize:10)
    btn3.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    let item3 = UIBarButtonItem()
    item3.customView = btn3

    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    space.width = -8

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [ item1, item2 , space ,item3]
}
```

How to reduce/increase the gap between the Notification title and the badge icon and  . The fixed space dosen't seem to work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative value for spacing does not work. However positive values do.